# property 'chartHeight' does not exist on type 'ChartObject'

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

I have one chart object in which some properties are there, using `this.chart.ref` I can access it, the problem here is it doesn't show 'chartHeight' property in my IDE.

[image]

But in my developer console, that property is available. That too with some integer value.

[image]

How to get this property that I'm getting in my developer console into my IDE so that I can use it?

Comment: this.statsChart['ref']['chartHeight']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Your IDE doesnt know , whats in the object , dont use dot notation. Use

```
     this.statsChart['ref']['chartHeight']
```

You can refer this https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3126-object-access-bracket-notation-vs-dot-notation-with-typescript-in-angular-2-rc-4.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JSDoc, yet?
See http://usejsdoc.org/tags-property.html

Using JSDoc can help recognizing properties which are otherwise difficult to detect for your IDE.